# asp.net application keeps running even after Application_Error finishes

Tags: c#, asp.net

the application keeps running even after Application_Error event is called, is there any way to terminate the application in that event itself

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want the website to shutdown completely? Do you simply want the worker thread to terminate?

Comment: Could you give some more detail as to why you want to do this? It sounds potentially like a flawed design.

Comment: i have a wcf service hosted in a windows service...and when the windows service is down and if someone tries to access the website i want to show them the error page which i have created,but whenever an error occurs, the exception is stored in the session and redirect to the error page(where i retireive the exception and show it there), but the problem is that even if one exception occured and i redirected to the error page, the application continues to run and i keep getting other exceptions which again and again redirects to the error page with different errors each time

Comment: Have you cleared the error using Server.ClearError()?  Have you also made sure that the Error page handles errors itself? It sounds like an exception is being thrown on the Error page, which is unhandled.  The Application level error handling kicks in, which is redirecting back to the Error page, which again is throwing another exception.

The Error page needs to be thoroughly bullet proof.

Comment: hey Matthew....u were right...please put it as answer so i can mark it

Answer (score 1):

That would be bad design IMO.  Unlike desktop applications, ASP.NET applications gracefully deal with unhandled exceptions by allowing the application to keep running.  If it didn't, the website would no longer accept incoming requests, is that what you really want to do?

Answer (score 0):

"After the Page_Error is called, the Application_Error sub is called. **Here you can also log the error and redirect to another page**. I won't explain anything else about it because it is basically the same as the Page_Error but happens to be at the application level rather than the page level."

Have a look at [this web application error handling suggestions](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/030102.htm).